Can I use my Business Visa application as a proof for Wife's tourist Visa ? (schengen germany)
I have applied for an urgent business visa through VFS Mumbai, India. My purpose of travel to Germany is business for the entire month of October. My wife(recently married) wants to join me on my 2nd week there and wants to stay with me there for 2 weeks.
Problem: My appointment was on 28th August, and my hotels are booked by my firm's corporate card. The hotel voucher mentions (1 guest 1 room). My firm won't sponsor any dependent's travel. Now, while applying for my wife's visa (appointment 9th Sept):

Do I need to book a separate room in that same hotel ? As my wife would require hotel accommodation documentation for visa.
Should I contact the hotel separately and ask for an updated voucher for an additional guest ? Do hotels provide that in general ? All the payments would have to be done on-site anyways.
Anyone who has recently applied via the German embassies. My travel dates are one month from the appointment date (both mine and my wife's). What's the chance of getting the visa on time ?
For my wife, i am providing the sponsorship letter + my appointment receipts as well. Does this weaken my application and increase the chance of cancellation ?


All this seems moot unless and until your own visa has been approved, as you’ll need to submit evidence of that with your wife’s application. Did you pay extra for an expedited decision? For Q2, you should ask the hotel, it may be that the room your firm has paid for will not accommodate two people or has restrictions on the booking.

Spoke to the hotel, they can accommodate two people. With minimal charges for the additional person. My travel agents tell me to just provide my receipt. Another concern is the lack of appointment dates, the next appointment date at VFS for German embassy is late October which is my time of arrival. I got lucky when I saw a cancellation at the VFS website, and immediately booked her appointment

It depends on the hotels, but business hotel usually allow you to upgrade and you will pay just the extra. But the timeline seems tight.


Q1 & Q2 Do I need to book a separate room in that same hotel? Should I contact the hotel separately and ask for an updated voucher for an additional guest?

From your comment, you’ve resolved this question yourself by contacting the hotel direct to confirm they can accommodate the additional person, and you will have a receipt for the extra guest fee to submit with your wife’s visa application.

Q3 My travel dates are one month from the appointment date (both mine and my wife's). What's the chance of getting the visa on time?

The standard processing time is within 15 calendar days, but can be up to 45 days

Q4: For my wife, i am providing the sponsorship letter + my appointment receipts as well. Does this weaken my application and increase the chance of cancellation ?

Since the purpose of your wife’s intended travel is to accompany you during part of your own trip, IMHO ideally you will need to submit a copy of your own visa with your wife’s application. IDK if providing just your appointment receipt will suffice, however If I were you I would ask VFS if it is possible to link your wife’s application to your own earlier one in this way.

Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the hotel told me they can't provide the updated voucher and will only onboard the additional guest onsite. They asked if a print out of my email chain with them would help along with my reservation. But I doubt it would. Although, great idea of contacting vfs to check if they can link it. A glimmer of hope. Else i will have to cancel my wife's appointment. I just don't want this application to cancel my application
